# EF Core - Join on 2 IQueryable that one of them has group by not translated to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I want to join two tables with EF Core with this code:

```
var fromDate = model.FromDate;
var toDate = model.ToDate;
var tourDate = _eContext.TourDates.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Where(x =>
(fromDate == null || x.Date >= fromDate) && (toDate == null || x.Date <= toDate))
    .GroupBy(x => x.TourId).Select(g => new { TourId = g.Key, TourDateID = g.Min(y => y.TourDateId) });

var tours1 = _eContext.TourDetails;

var joinres = tours1.Join(tourDate
    , tu => tu.TourDateId, td => td.TourDateId, (tu, td) => new { TourId = tu.TourId, TourDetailId = tu.Id, TourDateId = td.TourDateID });

var TourList = joinres.ToList();
```

When I execute the `.ToList()` method, I get this warning:

> The LINQ expression 'join TourDate td in
>   value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ModelLayer.EuropaMundo.TourDate])
>   on [td].TourDateID equals [td].TourDateId' could not be translated and
>   will be evaluated locally.

Is there any way to translate LINQ to SQL?

Comment: It's warning you about the fact it's unable to do the evaluation on the server. Rather it needs to process it locally. Which is something you need to explicitly allow. You usually want to write your query differently because local evaluation might result into large amounts of data being transferred to the client.

Comment: Basically, as far as I know, to explicitly opt-in for client-side evaluation, you have to call ToList() or ToEnumerable() before joining the two datasets.

Comment: You can just execute "RawSQL". I can't remember the specific method name, but you can do this an add a class to the EF context. It's quite hacky, I would instead investigate why the translation issue is occuring, linq is automatically converted to SQL, and executed as a stored procedure, the query you have built, is not correctly parsed into SQL syntax, as it is. 

While I am not sure why, as the DB structure is unknown, I can guess among a series of possibilities. you tour date id's aren't the same data type, the query itself has an invalid component, like the join needing to be executed.

Comment: What is the `OrderBy` for in the `tourDate` definition? What happens if you flip `tourDate` and `tours1` in the `Join`?

Comment: Thsi is not important, important thing is , join with min() column